# Gaussian surface difference between conductor and non-conducting sheet for calculation of eletric field

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law

For non-conducting sheet we select gaussian surface as cylinder with its end at the two opposite side of the sheet, but for conductor we select cylinder with one end inside the conductor. I know the flux through the circular cap of cylinder is zero inside conductor and that is the motivation to select such Gaussian surface, but what is the reason we can't select similar gaussian suface for conductor i.e cylinder passing through it.